# Update multiple columns in a single update query to autostack column values in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which stores a code in Stack1, Stack2, Stack3, Stack4,Stack5 and Stack6 column. In case user deletes one of the codes in any of these stacks, i have to autostack the remaining codes such that the gap can be moved to the last.

[image]

For Eg :- in the abovescreenshot, user has deleted code in Stack2, now i want code in stack3 to come in Stack2 and code in Stack4 to come in Stack3. Following is the expected output:

[image]

Please suggest solutions.

Comment: fix your UPDATE code to be smarter and shift values as necessary.  Also, I don't like this design.  I think it would be easier to have a child table and a different row for each `stack` value.  Whenever you repeat a column name and add a number onto that name, it should raise a really big red flag.

Comment: @KM -- spot on with the design problem.  I was typing the same thing at the same time:-)

Comment: You need a child "Stack" table......with something like an "Ordinal" (smallint) column.  Put a unique constraint on the Ordinal and a Check constraint (>0 and <=6).  The sql (for your issue) would be easier to do as well.

Comment: Dear All, i understand that it is a bad design, but it has been designed this way only and i cannot change this design. So sorry for the design part.

Comment: if you can only "delete" one at a time, I'd just go with 6 `IF` statements so you can run the simple `UPDATE` where you manually `SET` the columns, `CASE` free.  If columns 1 is deleted, your set col1=col2, col2=col3, col3=col4, col4=col5, col6=null; if col2 is deleted you set col2=col3, col3=col4, col4=col5, col6=null.  If you can "delete" multiple at a time, I'd concatenate the values into a CSV, split them, use ROW_NUMBER() to arrange them and join that to the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Gidil, this is no way a duplicate of the question you list. not even close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be nice to normalize your current schema, here is one possibility to update the table:

```
;with piv as (
    -- Unpivot the data for ordering
    select csCode, lane, [row], 1 as ordinal, stack1 as stack from MyTable
    union all select csCode, lane, [row], 2 as ordinal, stack2 as stack from MyTable
    union all select csCode, lane, [row], 3 as ordinal, stack3 as stack from MyTable
    union all select csCode, lane, [row], 4 as ordinal, stack4 as stack from MyTable
    union all select csCode, lane, [row], 5 as ordinal, stack5 as stack from MyTable
    union all select csCode, lane, [row], 6 as ordinal, stack6 as stack from MyTable
)
, sort as (
    -- Order the stacks
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by csCode, lane, [row] order by case when stack = '' then 1 else 0 end, ordinal) as stackNumber
    from piv
)
update a
    set stack1 = (select stack from sort where csCode = a.csCode and lane = a.lane and [row] = a.[row] and stackNumber = 1)
    , stack2 = (select stack from sort where csCode = a.csCode and lane = a.lane and [row] = a.[row] and stackNumber = 2)
    , stack3 = (select stack from sort where csCode = a.csCode and lane = a.lane and [row] = a.[row] and stackNumber = 3)
    , stack4 = (select stack from sort where csCode = a.csCode and lane = a.lane and [row] = a.[row] and stackNumber = 4)
    , stack5 = (select stack from sort where csCode = a.csCode and lane = a.lane and [row] = a.[row] and stackNumber = 5)
    , stack6 = (select stack from sort where csCode = a.csCode and lane = a.lane and [row] = a.[row] and stackNumber = 6)
from MyTable a
```

I'm using a couple of [CTEs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to unpivot and order the stacks, then updating each stack with a correlated subquery.  You can run this on the entire table, or provide a where clause as appropriate for better performance.

There are a couple of assumptions here:

- Your "blank" data is an empty string. If you might have spaces and nulls, sanitize that or qualify it with something like `ltrim(rtrim(coalesce(stack1, ''))) != ''`
- `csCode, lane, row` makes a candidate key (unique and none of those are null).  If `csCode` is the primary key by itself, then you wouldn't need `lane` or `row` in any of this query.

Answer (score -1):

Some combination of `Case` statements and `Coalesce` should get you there.  It's tough to provide precise code without all the edge case variations, but an *psuedo example* of what your asking *could* look like:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
       Stack1 =  Coalesce (Stack1, Stack2, Stack3, Stack4, Stack5, Stack6),
       Stack2 =  Coalesce (Stack2, Stack3, Stack4, Stack5, Stack6)
       Stack3 =  Coalesce (Stack3, Stack4, Stack5, Stack6),
       Stack4 =  Coalesce (Stack4, Stack5, Stack6),
       Stack5 =  Coalesce (Stack5, Stack6),
       Stack6 =  Stack6
WHERE ID = @SomeIDValue
```

With that said, your questions smells of a database design problem.  From what you've shared, I would rather have stack in a child table.

```
CodeParent
  * codeParentID
  * csCode
  * line
  * row

CodeStackChild
  * codeStackChildId  (int identity)
  * codeParentID
  *  stackValue
```

With a table setup like above you could delete a value in the middle of your stack and just move along without the need to shift values around.   To get values in order you just query the `CodeStackChild` table and use a `ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (Partition by codeParentID)` in your select statement.

Comment: Ouch.  What do you dislike?  Without his edge cases explained it's tough to understand if a stack value is blanked during update, or before.  Also to know if all values slide over or only just the nearest one.  Or if multiple stack values can be blanked at once.  That's why I put the disclaimer.

Comment: not my downvote, but you will have a repeating values.  for example, say stack3 is deleted. stack3 will get stack4 value, stack4 will get stack4 value, stack5 will get stack5 value, etc.

Comment: Exactly (not that I downvoted). This solution would leave a value in the OP's stack4 which should have been _moved_ to stack3.

Comment: Sure, that's why I referenced needing a combo of CASE & Coalesce.  I thought adding CASE statements for an unknown set of conditions would be more confusing than 'kind of' showing the idea.  I guess I've added to the confusion :-(

Answer (score -1):

You have to write a trigger, after update which will be checking recursively if a stack column is null, if that is the case then start updating stack[n-1] with stack [n], Nice question u asked.

Regards

Ashutosh Arya